# How to change measure unit in Character tool Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, font-size

I use pixels in my CSS code rather than points. However, the Character tool in PS CS6 shows the font size in points.

Any way to set the default unit of the Character tool to pixels?

Comment: FYI... to Adobe... 1pt = 1px so really... you don't need to change it if it's reading pts.

Answer (score 3):

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Go to Units & Rulers
- Go to Type and select Pixels